# How to check if element is tappable

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode-ui-testing

The app I am developing Xcode UI tests for has multiple back buttons in view. One is tappable and the other is not. I tried wrapping in a do/catch but the test will fail, if any single line fails.

app.navigationBars.buttons["Back"] has multiple matches, both:

```
app.navigationBars.childrenMatchingType(.Button).elementBoundByIndex(0)
```

and

```
app.navigationBars.childrenMatchingType(.Button).elementBoundByIndex(1)
```

Is it possible to try one and if not do the other one? Or check if the element is tappable?

Depending on size of device (6+ and iPad vs smaller devices), the back button element changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @dasdom's answer, you can do the following in Swift:

```
let buttonQuery = app.navigationBars.element.childrenMatchingType(.Button)
var button = buttonQuery.elementBoundByIndex(0)
if (button.hittable == false) {
    button = buttonQuery.elementBoundByIndex(1)
}
button.tap()
```

Note tat `button` is not optional, so no `?` is required. Also, the enum doesn't translate directly so `.Button` should be used.

Comment: I'll delete my answer as yours is the correct version of mine. :)

Comment: Didn't realize it was this easy and organized. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to add a tag with elements? I need to navigate all screen on bfs/dfs style. So how can we keep trace which element is already tapped?